# Graphical Google Maps error when using JQuery to show a hidden div

Tags: jquery, google-maps, html, show, hidden

I'm using JQuery to show a hidden div that contains a Google Map.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('#searchBox').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).val() == "london" || "LONDON") 
            $('#border').slideDown('fast')
        else 
            $('#border').slideUp('fast');
    }
});
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<div id = "border">
<div id = "map_canvas">
<div id="searchContainer">
<input id="searchBox" type="text" size="50"  placeholder="SEARCH">
```

And this is the result when I enter "london":
[image: Result]

The content of the map only shows in the top left corner, but the map is obviously there.

I'm using this code to link the search box with the map, but it's not perfect: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

p.s for some reason the return key doesn't work with the search box.

Comment: show your html markup

Comment: as a side note, I'd convert the input value to uppercase or lowercase and test against that - otherwise if I typed in "London", I would not get a result.

Comment: yeah, i'll be sure to do that.

Comment: Also, you can't do `$(this).val() == "london" || "LONDON"` - It would have to be `$(this).val() == "london" || $(this).val() == "LONDON"` - Each one has to be a comparison.

Comment: thanks. i'd rather it'd just show when enter is pressed, but for some reason `if (event.keyCode == 13) {` won't work.

Comment: when you hide a map and then display it again you have to trigger resize event on map each tme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through something similar when we were developing a site with Google Map functionality. Add this line to see if the problem goes away:

```
//Test for hidden div map
google.maps.event.trigger([your_map_variable], 'resize');
```

It's a fairly common issue when dealing with Google maps in a hidden div.

Comment: that sort of solved the problem, but there are still some issues. hold on.

Comment: i'm using this code for the autocomplete in the search bar: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: You seem to be on to a separate issue. Are you saying that the places autocomplete functionality isn't working? Your code listing above is incomplete to try and diagnose what the problem may be there. Based on your comment about the enter key not working, I can only guess that some line is throwing an error. What do your developer tools reveal?

Comment: well, you're right it is a separate error. although the example google provides does not allow you to search without selecting a selection from the list. for example, typing "london" and hitting return does nothing. your solution seems to have solved the original issue.